# python and py2app mac osx 10.7

Tags: python, macos, py2app

i want to create .app application by Py2app, i was installed Py2app on my mac os x lion by terminal and copy "gtkapp.py" (the name of my app that used PyGTK) and "setup.py"  but when i run the setup.py get this error:

```
from setuptools import setup
```

and

```
ImportError: cannot import name setup
```

what problem?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the py2app binary is in your path. A simple way around this is to use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) for your py2app isntallation.